# Added Client IP is not persisted in Azure Server Firewall settings

Tags: azure, firewall

I need to add my current IP address as a "accept" rule in one of the servers.

1. Going to Server page -> Firewalls and virtual networks,
2. I see that there are no firewall rules configured

[image]

3. I click "Add Client IP" and I see this added to the list with appropriate IP addresses

[image]

4. I click save and see message

[image]

and modal

[image]

and my list now looks like this:

[image] .

But after doing hard reset this entry disappears:

[image]

**What is the reason for this?**

Answer (score 0):

I hope we are talking about Azure SQL Firewall Rules, it could be Azure UI glitch.
Try to do it via Powershell:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#use-powershell-to-manage-server-level-ip-firewall-rules

Or Az Cli (cloud shell will work as well): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/firewall-configure#use-cli-to-manage-server-level-ip-firewall-rules